# How can I create a modal and render it on the fly?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am building my first app in React Native, I have a ListView that displays a number of items and each one is clickable. My question is when I click on a row I would like a modal to appear above. Similar in IOS to clicking and the adding a subview.

```
renderRow( rowData ){
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.pressRow()}>
        <View style={styles.parcelInfoContainer}>

        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
```

Now the problem is I am unsure about what to do in the function called by pressRow in relation to rendering the new component. In IOS I would simply add the view at this point but I am not sure how to go about it in React Native. I understand the idea of components just not how to render a new component on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to render the same Modal, in terms of layout, you should define it in render() function. Rendering on the fly is not possible, but you can change the states to make modal show what you like.

```
onPressRow = (dataFromRow) => {
  this.setState({
    modalText: dataFromRow.text
  })
  this.showModal(); //Call your function to show modal
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList />
      <Modal>
        <View>
          ...
          <Text>{this.state.modalText}</Text>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  )
}
```

However, if you want different layout for each row, you should write a `this.getModalContent()` like function to determine which layout should be rendered. You should call this function in render => `<Modal> {this.getModalContent()} </Modal>`

```
getModalContent = () => {
  switch (this.state.modalText) { // define a better logic here.
    case 'a':
      return ( <Text> hey </Text>)
    ...
  }
}
```